# Does -[NSInvocation retainArguments] copy blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain, nsinvocation

`NSInvocation`'s `-retainArguments` method is useful for when you don't run the `NSInvocation` immediately, but do it later; it retains the object arguments so they remain valid during this time.

As we all know, block arguments should be copied instead of retained. My question is, does `-retainArguments` know to copy instead of retain an argument when it's of block type? The documentation does not indicate that it does, but it seems like an easy and sensible thing to do.

**Update:** The behavior seems to have changed in iOS 7. I just tested this, and in iOS 6.1 and before, `-retainArguments` didn't copy parameters of block type. In iOS 7 and later, `-retainArguments` does copy parameters of block type. The documentation of `-retainArguments` has been updated to say that it copies blocks, but it does not say when the behavior changed (which is really dangerous for people who support older OS's).

Comment: Thanks for keeping this updated!

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly supposed to (albeit I haven't test it myself).  According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsinvocation_class/reference/reference.html):

> retainArguments
>
> If the receiver hasn’t already done so, retains the
>   target and all object arguments of the receiver and copies all of its
>   C-string arguments and blocks.
>
> - (void)retainArguments
>
> Discussion
>
> Before this method is invoked, argumentsRetained returns NO; after, it returns YES.
>
> For efficiency, newly created NSInvocation objects don’t retain or
>   copy their arguments, nor do they retain their targets, copy C
>   strings, or copy any associated blocks. You should instruct an
>   NSInvocation object to retain its arguments if you intend to cache it,
>   because the arguments may otherwise be released before the invocation
>   is invoked. NSTimer objects always instruct their invocations to
>   retain their arguments, for example, because there’s usually a delay
>   before a timer fires.

Comment: Interesting. The documentation has changed: https://web.archive.org/web/20120826185131/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSInvocation/retainArguments But it does not document if and when the behavior changed. Blocks were definitely not copied by `retainArguments` when I tried it in iOS 6 a year ago.

Comment: I just tested it, and it is copied in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6.1, so it changed.

Comment: They should've documented the change as an ios 7 update as opposed to making it seem like it's always been this way... silly Apple, tricks are for kids!

Answer (score 1):

No.

Image if the answer is yes, where `NSInvocation` is smart enough to copy block, it should do something like this:

```
for (/*every arguments*/) {
    if (/*arg is object. i.e. @encode(arg) is '@'*/) {
        if ([arg isKindOfClss:[NSBlock class]]) {
            arg = [arg copy]; // copy block
        } else {
            [arg retain];
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that `arg` is modified while copying the block, which should not happen because this means call `retainArguments` may change the arguments in the `NSInvocation`. <del>this will break many assumptions that already made. (i.e. arguments get from `NSInvocation` should be same as arguments used to create the `NSInvocation`)</del>

---

**Update**

just did the test to conform the answer is **NO**, but my previous point was incorrect though...

```
@interface Test : NSObject

@end

@implementation Test

- (void)testMethodWithBlock:(void (^)(void))block obj:(id)obj cstr:(const char *)cstr {
    NSLog(@"%p %p %p %@", block, obj, cstr, [block class]);
}

@end

@implementation testTests

- (void)test1 {
    __block int dummy;
    Test *t = [[Test alloc] init];
    NSMethodSignature *ms = [t methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(testMethodWithBlock:obj:cstr:)];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:ms];
    void (^block)(void) = ^ {
        dummy++;    // stop this become global block
    };
    id obj = @"object";
    char *cstr = malloc(5);
    strcpy(cstr, "cstr");


    NSLog(@"%@", [ms debugDescription]);

    NSLog(@"%p %p %p %@", block, obj, cstr, [block class]);

    [invocation setSelector:@selector(testMethodWithBlock:obj:cstr:)];
    [invocation setArgument:&block atIndex:2];
    [invocation setArgument:&obj atIndex:3];
    [invocation setArgument:&cstr atIndex:4];

    [invocation invokeWithTarget:t];

    [invocation retainArguments];

    [invocation invokeWithTarget:t];

    free(cstr);
}

@end
```

output, ARC disabled (and crashed):

```
2013-04-18 19:49:27.616 test[94555:c07] 0xbfffe120 0x70d2254 0x7167980 __NSStackBlock__
2013-04-18 19:49:27.617 test[94555:c07] 0xbfffe120 0x70d2254 0x7167980 __NSStackBlock__
2013-04-18 19:49:27.618 test[94555:c07] 0xbfffe120 0x70d2254 0x736a810 __NSStackBlock__
```

ARC enabled:

```
2013-04-18 19:51:03.979 test[95323:c07] 0x7101e10 0x70d2268 0x7101aa0 __NSMallocBlock__
2013-04-18 19:51:03.979 test[95323:c07] 0x7101e10 0x70d2268 0x7101aa0 __NSMallocBlock__
2013-04-18 19:51:03.980 test[95323:c07] 0x7101e10 0x70d2268 0xe0c1310 __NSMallocBlock__
```

as you can see, c string are copied by `retainArguments` but not blocks. but with ARC enabled, the problem should go away because ARC copied it for you at some point.

Comment: Copying a block doesn't change what the type system cares about, the block's signature.  Sure, it may go from an `__NSStackBlock__` to an `__NSHeapBlock__`, but that's the point of copying a block: moving it to the heap to extend its lifetime.

Comment: Good point. However, `-retainArguments` also copies C strings. And copying C strings also changes the arguments.

Comment: @CodaFi my point is `block != [block copy]` so it may cause problem if is copied

Comment: @user102008 i never know that... can you give me reference? and i will try it when i have time

Comment: @xlc: yes, the documentation for the `retainArguments` method. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSInvocation/retainArguments

Comment: "output, ARC disabled (and crashed)" you must be running some other code than what you have shown, because what you have shown should not crash. The block is in scope until the end of `test1`, including where the `NSInvocation` is invoked.

Comment: @user102008 that's all code and i am running it as unit test. it crashed because `__NSStackBlock__` is added to autorelease pool, so the reference of the block is get extended beyond the scope